# Firebase dynamic link opens playstore randomly, but app is already installed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

Sometimes, dynamic link works well. But some times, it just open google play store and this is the problem.

Especially, it shows google play store more frequently when then app is not running.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

---

**Edit:**

I tried following sequence and failed:

- Click link send by Whats app
- Web browser opens
- Google play store app opens <= Just shows my app, with "Open" button

But by this sequence, it was successful.

- One web browser was already opened
- Click link on Whats app
- Everything is fine, deeplink params delievered.

---

- I followed this official example, 
  https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/dynamiclinks/app

- And this is my dynamic link 
  https://stanleyko.page.link/?amv=0&apn=com.stanleyko.fdl&link=https%3A%2F%2Fkotlin.example.com%2Fdeeplinks%3Fearn%3Dq1w2e3r4

- This is my intent-filter.

  ```
  <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

      <data
          android:host="truebalance.io/products"
          android:scheme="https" />
  </intent-filter>
  ```
- And this is my google play store url. 
  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stanleyko.fdl

Comment: Try adding one more scheme for http 
 **<data
        android:host="truebalance.io/products"
        android:scheme="http" />**

Comment: @NileshRathore, I tried but no luck.

Comment: `products` should be a path parameter.

Comment: @tynn That's right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key point was adding application id. With this option, the link will launch app directly and will not open google play store if app was already installed.

```
Firebase.dynamicLinks.shortLinkAsync {
    domainUriPrefix = MY_PREFIX
    androidParameters(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID) {
        minimumVersion = MY_MIN_VERSION
    }
    link = myDeepLink // My deep link
}.addOnSuccessListener { result ->
    val shortLink = result.shortLink
    // Use shortLink
}.addOnFailureListener {
    // Do something
}
```

I have found the answer from below. Details:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51224484/850347

Comment: Even with this is does not always work reliably. But why would it? It's Android/Google after all.

Comment: For it It was casused by the minimumversion code. I used 8, but my android/build.gradle has versionCode7. So it was treated like oldder app, and it navigated me to store.